# A few problems after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, login, lightdm

First off, let me say, I don't believe this to be a duplicate as I've tried everything I can find.

Last week, I started the upgrade process to Ubuntu 15.10 from 14.04. I did the upgrade to 15.04, which seemed to turn out fine. I could log in and use the computer, and nothing seemed to be missing. I then opened a terminal and started the upgrade to 15.10.

This also seemed to go well, occasionally confirming whether I wanted to replace some config files or whether I wanted to keep them as they were. Some were config files for `fglrx`, and I kept them the same. I don't think this is the problem, but I thought I'd include it.

So, the upgrade process finished and I answered "yes" to the reboot prompt. Now, here's where the problems started. The computer rebooted and the bootlogo showed up fine, but once it finished booting, I was left with a blank screen that would occasionally flash some text. I took a video of the screen so I could look at what the text said and none of it was useful.

Now, here's where I need to put some background in. I originally installed normal Ubuntu 14.04, with Unity and `lightdm`, then installed KDE on top of that. Because of KDE's Xorg memory leak problem, I ended up installing GNOME to get rid of it. I now had three desktop environments and had `gdm` in use instead of `lighdm`.

Back to the problem: Since I couldn't even get to the login screen, I decided to switch to `lightdm` to see if anything would happen. I managed to do this using a TTY and rebooted into `lightdm`, which showed up fine. I tried to login, but was instantly kicked back to the login screen. I made a new account through the terminal, but that didn't help.

I then went back to the TTY and proceeded to purge `xserver-xorg` and reinstall it, purge GNOME and reinstall it, purge Unity and reinstall it, and just purge KDE completely. Now, after all of this, when I try to login to either Unity or GNOME, I get a blank screen for a few seconds and then a "System Problem Detected" window. I can't see what the problem is as hitting Report does nothing and I eventually get kicked back to the login screen.

It almost seems like something is crashing so I get kicked back, but I can't figure out what. I can do a fresh install, but it would be much less of a hassle to be able to fix this, as I have configs everywhere that would need to be transferred.

Any suggestions (even dupe flags) are greatly appreciated. Sorry for the long question.

***EDIT***

My problems just kept getting worse until the computer finally wouldn't boot. It now just shows a blinking cursor and kills the keyboard no matter which option in GRUB I choose. I will leave this question here, but I've given up and am reinstalling. If you do have suggestions or answers, feel free to post them, as they may help others.

Comment: You may have a hardware fault, which can be checked by running tests from the Utimate Boot CD (see http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). If this were the case though, you will still have problems when you reinstall.

Comment: @Scooby-2 I reinstalled already. Everything's fine now that I'm reconfigured. Thanks though.